Isomorphism of topological groups
Question: Let $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})$ be the subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ generated by $\{\sqrt{x} : x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})$ is Galois, and that the map
$\psi : \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}) / \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \{\pm 1\}) : \sigma \mapsto (a \mapsto \sigma(\sqrt{a})/\sqrt{a})$
is an isomorphism of topological groups, if $ \text{Hom} (\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \{ \pm 1 \} )$ has the relative topology inside $\{ \pm 1 \}^{\mathbb{Q}^{*}}$. Prove also that this Galois group is isomorphic to the product of a countable infinite collection of copies of $\pm 1$.
My attempt: First I thought we could recognize the field as
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \dots)$. This field extension is clearly algebraic, also separable since the characteristic is 0. Furthermore this extension is normal because for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})$ we can consider $f^{\alpha}_{\mathbb{Q}} = X^{2} - \alpha^{2}$ to see that this polynomial splits into linear factors in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})[X]$. Hence, it is a Galois extension.
To show that $\psi$ is a group morphism, let $\sigma, \tau \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}) / \mathbb{Q})$ and let $a \in \mathbb{Q}^{*}$. then we have that
$\frac{\sigma(\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}} \cdot \frac{\tau(\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}} = \frac{\sigma(\sqrt{a} \cdot \frac{\tau(\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}})}{\sqrt{a}} = \frac{(\sigma \circ \tau)(\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}}$.
Hence, $\psi$ is a group morphism. For injectivity, suppose that $\sigma \in \ker\psi$. Then $\sigma$ must be de identity on all $\sqrt{a}$ for $a \in \mathbb{Q}^{*}$. But then $\sigma$ is the identity on all the generators of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})$, so $\sigma$ must be the identity. Hence, $\ker\psi$ is trivial and thus $\psi$ is injective.
Here I am a bit stuck, I am struggling to finish the proof that $\psi$ is an isomorphism of topological groups. If anybody has hints on how to proceed I would appreciate that. Furthermore, I would like to hear if my following argument is correct for proving that the Galois group is isomorphic to the product of a countable infinite collection of copies of $\{ \pm 1\}$: The way we identified $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})$ as the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \dots)$ gives us an isomorphism
$\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}) / \mathbb{Q}) \cong \{\pm 1\} \times \prod_{p \text{ prime }} \{\pm 1\}$ since we can flip the sign of any $\alpha$ being a generator. Each one of these non-trivial automorphisms of order 2 will correspond with a copy of $\{\pm 1\}$. Furthermore it is an infinite amount of copies since each $\sqrt{p_{i}}$ and $\sqrt{p_{j}}$ are linearly independent.
Edit: I think the idea is to endow $\{ \pm 1 \}^{\mathcal{P}}$ where $\mathcal{P} = \{-1\} \cup \{p : p \text{ prime}\}$ with the product topology and then show that $\psi$ is continuous, since a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Does this question come from a textbook? I'd be interested to know what book covers these topics.

This question is from the following syllabus: https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf (the question in this post is question 2.14 in the syllabus)

You never showed $\psi$ is surjective, so you can't say you showed yet that the Galois group (merely as a group, ignoring the topology) is isomorphic to the infinite product of $\{\pm 1\}$ that you wrote down.
Have you learned about the Krull topology that all infinite Galois groups have, and that makes them all compact Hausdorff topological groups? Show (i) $\psi$ is continuous when the Galois group has the Krull topology and (ii) the image of $\psi$ is dense by showing some dense subset of the infinite product of $\{\pm 1\}$ (with the product topology) is in the image. By (i), the image is compact, and thus closed (the product topology here is Hausdorff), so (ii) implies the image is the whole product.  Then you can wrap things up the way you indicated in your edit.
